# Sending file of custom python script with all parameters for popup interface already defined?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, export

I have a python script in ArcGIS 10 that when clicked, has a popup for a user to choose parameters. I would like to send this file to someone else. While I could send them the python code and have them setup the parameters - this method repeats work I have already done.

I would like to send someone one file that contains all of this information so they can just recieve my file, add it to a toolbox, and then have it all work. I am wondering where the file resides that has both the python code and parameters / what is the export process/ file type I should be looking at? (All the searches I do for "export script" seem to refer to exporting a model to python code...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as per @Chad Cooper's answer, you send the custom toolbox (*.tbx file) and the python script. There are instructions in the [online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Methods_for_distributing_tools/005700000003000000/) to do this.

Comment: Further to that, you can [embed the Python script directly to the toolbox](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Embedding_scripts_and_password_protecting_tools/005700000017000000/), even with an optional password for protection.

Comment: I think this is the key info I was looking for. As a semi-aside: is there any way of looking at the properties of the toolbox to see if it has script embedded or not?

Comment: interestingly this embed method does not seem to embed any code from my few tests... (when I went to open the toolbox from another computer)

Comment: think i figured out why this did not work (see comment in response to blah238's answer)

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want to do is create a custom Toolbox tool and setup your parameters there. Then you would ship others your code along with the .tbx Toolbox file. See [this section](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/) of the ArcGIS help.

[image]

Comment: This is indeed how I have done it. But what you are saying is to pass along a python script and its popup interface, I need to send the whole toolbox rather than the actual script for someone to add to their own toolbox?

Comment: Sending the whole toolbox indeed works! Just had to get over trying to find a way to export the script itself. Thanks

Comment: Found out that is worked - but only to bring up the interface, but the tool itself didnt work - apparently I also need to embed the script

Comment: @GIStack - I believe you can also just point the .tbx to wherever the script resides on disk.

Comment: indeed - sending two separate files, with the one being the script seems to be the only viable solution if I am using ArcGIS 10, and the other person is using ArcGIS 9

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying your script tool and specifying default values, I would use [ModelBuilder](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w00000001000000) to do this.

1. Create a ModelBuilder model in the same toolbox.
2. Drop your custom script tool in.
3. Fill out the parameters.
4. For any variables that you want the user to be able to change, even though they have a default value, right click the variable and select "Make model parameter".
5. Save the model.
6. Send the toolbox and Python script file. You can also embed the Python script in the toolbox as @Mike Toews mentioned.

Also be sure to use [relative paths](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Paths_explained_Absolute_relative_UNC_and_URL/005700000009000000/) in your model and script tool properties so that the script, model and script tool can find each other on the client's machine:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that unless "relative paths" is selected because embedding the script to the toolbox, the tool won't work on a different computer?

Comment: If you are NOT embedding the script, then the script referenced by the script tool will likely not be found on the client's file system, because the absolute path to the script on your machine would likely be different to the absolute path to the script on the client's machine. When you use relative paths then as long as the toolbox and script are kept together it will work on any machine. I am not sure about whether ModelBuilder will have trouble finding the script tool without relative paths checked if they are in the same toolbox, but I generally always check the box out of habit.

Comment: Ok - i just tried both ways (absolute and relative) and neither work. I do not understand why using the "embed script" method did not embed anything (When I go to edit the script that i emailed myself to a different computer, the editor does not come up because there is nothing to edit)... I must be missing something here..

Comment: I think i figured out my problem - I was trying to open a toolbox with embedded code on ArcGIS 9. It seems that embedded script is only supported by ArcGIS 10.